# Android - Button does not appear

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to make an application with just a button.

I'm using Intellij Design tool to make my layout and all seems ok but when I try to run the app, I have no button on my screen.

Here is my activity file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.test.button test.MainActivity" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <Button
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1" tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit :
Changing android:layout_width="0dp" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" does not change anything.

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" => android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: You have    android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: Still not working with layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

You gave width 0 to your Button. So that is not visible to you.Give width to it.
Use below code for Button;

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/join_now"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Join Now"/>
```

Comment: Remove this two lines:  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using ConstraintLayout,  which will reset all your Buttons to (0,0) if no constraint is given.
Try using RelativeLayout or setting constraints.